# Missing an error when incorrectly passing string to printf-style log function

Tags: c++, gcc

It is very common for any medium-to-large project to replace `printf` with a custom log function. Here is a minimal C++ example and its usage:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string>

void log_printf(const char* fmt, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    vprintf(fmt, ap); // real code obviously does something fancier
    va_end(ap);
}

int main() {
    std::string x = "Hello";

    // correct code
    printf("String is %s\n", x.c_str());
    log_printf("String is %s\n", x.c_str());

    // incorrect code
    printf("String is %s\n", x); // bad line 1
    log_printf("String is %s\n", x); // bad line 2
}
```

The simple logger receives a variable amount of arguments and calls `vprintf` to output them to standard output. The lines under 'correct code' demonstrate correct usage of this logger. My question involves the 'bad' lines, where a string object is incorrectly passed instead of a pointer to the character buffer.

Under GCC 4.6 (tested under Linux) neither of the bad lines can compile, which is a good thing because I want to catch such incorrect usage. The error is:

```
error: cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type ‘std::string {aka struct std::basic_string<char>}’ through ‘...’
```

However in GCC 5.1 it has apparently become possible to pass non-trivially-copyable objects, and the compilation succeeds. If I use -Wall then only 'bad line 1' raises a warning about an unexpected argument type, but 'bad line 2' with the log_printf compiles without issue in any case. Needless to say both lines produce garbage output.

I can catch 'bad line 1' with `-Wall -Werror`, but what about 'bad line 2'? How can I cause it to also generate a compilation error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your own functions you need to use a [common function attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes) call `format`:

```
void log_printf(const char* fmt, ...) __attribute__((format (printf, 1, 2)));

void log_printf(const char* fmt, ...) {
    ...
}
```

<sub>Note that the attribute must be set on a function *declaration*, not the definition.</sub>

The first argument to the `format` attribute is the style, in this case `printf` (`scanf` is also possible, for functions that works like `scanf`), the second argument is the format string, and the third argument is where the ellipsis `...` is. It will help GCC check the format strings like for the standard `printf` function.

This is a GCC extension, though some other compilers have adopted it to become GCC compatible, most notably the Intel C compiler ICC and Clang (the standard compiler used on OSX and some BSD variants). The Visual Studio compiler does not have this extension, and I know of no similar thing for Visual C++.

Comment: @José You mean it doesn't show the warnings? Try it in a non-online compiler and you will see them. Neither that, nor Ideone seems to show warnings.